# Placing a tkinter label on screen for a few seconds then destroying it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So when you run the code below the tkinter label (and the whole window) doesn't appear at all for the few seconds then the window shows up without the label. I want to display the label for a few seconds, then for it to go away after a few seconds.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

busted_display = Label(root, text="My Label Widget", 
    font=("arial", "15"))
busted_display.place(x=0, y=0)
print("it ran")
time.sleep(3)
print("and then this ran")
busted_display.destroy()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use time.sleep in an event driven program like a GUI. In tkinter, the answer to timed operations is the `after()` method, which runs the code you give it after a certain amount of milliseconds.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

busted_display = Label(root, text="My Label Widget", font=("arial", "15"))
busted_display.place(x=0, y=0)
root.after(2000, busted_display.destroy)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ahh yes this work but you also need to use root.update_idletasks() before the 'after' method in order to get this to work

Comment: ... and for that matter you can use time.sleep() with success as long as you use the root.update_idletasks() method

Comment: @NoahCaldwell no you don't need anything else to make this work; I tested it before I posted. And if you have `update_idletasks()` anywhere in your code it's a sign that your code went wrong elsewhere. Good code would nearly never use `update_idletasks()`.