# In tkinter I am changing label text with time.sleep() method. The function contains two same labels

Tags: python, tkinter

```
lbl_txt = config(text="text 1")
time.sleep(2)
lbl_txt = config(text="text 2")
```

When running the code 2nd label is showing but first is not showing. First label 1 should show and after 2 seconds second label should show

Comment: You can't use time.sleep in an event driven program like a GUI.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997984/placing-a-tkinter-label-on-screen-for-a-few-seconds-then-destroying-it) question

Comment: is there any way to show the first text and then the second one

Comment: @Luke, you can use `time.sleep` but it would not work.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.after` instead of `time.sleep` because it messes the tkinter mainloop

And your `config` statement syntax is wrong, from `lbl_txt = config(text="text 1")` to `lbl_txt.config(text="text 1")`

Look at this example -

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
lbl_txt = tk.Label(root)
lbl_txt.pack()

lbl_txt.config(text="text 1")

root.after(2000,lambda:lbl_txt.config(text='text 2')) # 2000 is 2 seconds

root.mainloop()
```